# How to find my link in an external domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to program an automatic link exchange

- First: Visitor must put my link in his/her website.
- Second: In my website, visitor fills a textbox (html) that get the target domain that contains my link.
- Third: I must find my link in the target domain before I put the target domain's link in my website. If I found, then I put her/his link in my website.

I want to find my link in for example :[shaarzh[dot]com](http://shaarzh.com) (just domain name, without any web page)

please help me to find my link by javascript or jquery

Comment: You cannot do that in javascript due to same origin policy. You have to proxified it server side using e.g cUrl in PHP

Comment: thanks
But I can't do with php
becuase I want it in a blog service
I tried with a div but there is a question in my mind: is there any way to convert the div to javascript string,then search the string?

Comment: At least you have a server right?! Like i said, this must be done on a server, not client side

Comment: $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">'); how to convert siteloader to an array of links or to string ?

Comment: How will you save data in javascript?

Comment: thanks alot to @AhmedHabib for his right answer

Comment: What 'blog service' are you operating - the vast majority of them (wordpress for example) are written in PHP. Aside from that - if you have a webserver hosting the site, more than likely you can still upload a PHP script to the server and access it via an AJAX call on your page in the method alexP has used below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do that on server side e.g. with PHP

PHP(checkDomain.php):

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('http://www.shaarzh.com'); //Get external content
$reg = '/example.com/s'; //Search pattern
if(preg_match($reg, $string)){
    $array = array('response' => 'true');
}else{
    $array = array('response' => 'false');
}
    echo json_encode( array('response'=>'false') ); //Response
?>
```

Now you can call the PHP-script with JavaScript.

JavaScript(jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "checkDomain.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.response);
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks But I can't do with php becuase I want it in a blog service